Question to find points of intersection and altitudes with circumcircle and then multiply the three complex numbers
Let A(3,4), B(-4,3) and C(4,3) be the vertices of ΔABC. ΔАВС is inscribed in a circle S = 0 Let AD, BE and CF be the altitudes from A to BC, B to AC and C to AB respectively. AD, BE and CF are extended to meet S = 0 in $D(z_{1}$),  $E(z_{2}$) and $F(z_{3}$) respectively. (Here $z_{1}, z_{2}$  and $z_{3}$ are three complex numbers).
Find the value of $z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}$
I have found out a method to solve this and I am getting the correct answer but I would like to know a shorter method (more elegant) since this one involves a bit of calculation.
We can clearly observe that the circumcenter of the triangle ABC is (0,0). We can also find the the centroid (1,10/3). We know that centroid divides orthocenter and circumcenter in the ratio 2:1. So we can can use this property to find orthocenter(comes out to be (3,10). Then, we know that the image of orthocenter about any side of the triangle lies on circumcircle. So I am finding the image of orthocenter about each side and finding the exact coordinates of D, E and F and then multiplying the three complex numbers to get the final answer.
D = (4.68,-1.76)
E = (3,-4)
F = (-3,4)
Final Answer = 75+100i
Is it possible to somehow directly get the value of $z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}$ without having to individually find the points?

It's an obtuse angle triangle, which puts $F$ outside the circle. Is $CF$ extended backwards?

Why will F lie outside circle

D, E and F lie on the circ;e

Lemma : Let $A(a), B(b), C(c), D(d)$ lie on circle with centre origin and radius $r$. If $AD \perp BC$ then
$d= -bc/a$
Proof : $\frac{d-a}{c-b}$ is purely imaginary. So
$$ \frac{d-a}{c-b} + \overline{ \Big( \frac{d-a}{c-b} \Big) } = 0 $$
$$ \frac{d-a}{c-b} + \frac{r^2/d- r^2/a}{r^2/c- r^2/b}  = 0 $$
$$ \frac{d-a}{c-b} \Big(1 + \frac{bc}{ad} \Big) = 0 $$
$$d= -bc/a$$
In second line, $ a\bar{a} = |a|^2 = r^2 \Rightarrow \bar{a} = r^2/a $.
Using for above problem
$$ def = -\frac{bc}{a} \times -\frac{ca}{b} \times -\frac{ab}{c} = -abc = 75 + 100i $$
